# How to successively change a class on click

Tags: jquery, removeclass

Suppose I have a list of div:

```
<div id='d-1' class='hidden'>this one<br />
    <button onclick='next();'>Next</button>
</div>
<div id='d-2' class='show'>Second one
<br />
    <button onclick='next();'>Next</button>
</div>
<div id='d-2' class='hidden'>Third one<br />
    <button onclick='next();'>Next</button>
</div>
<div id='d-2' class='hidden'>Fouth one
<br />
    <button onclick='next();'>Next</button>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.show {
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  color: green;
}
```

how can I change the classes successively？

I try to do it by:

```
$(function(){
 function next(){
 $(this).removeclass('show').addclass('hidden');
 }
});
```

any help? here is my code in[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/115/):

**EDIT**

Updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/127/)

Comment: What do you mean by changing them "successively"? You should also format your requests with a proper: `$(document).ready( function() { $('.do_next').click( function() { ... do stuff here ... } } );`, then assign a class **do_next** to your buttons. This will then trigger the clicks (better than doing it *onclick*)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fCuX2/1/

Comment: The `next()` method arent in scope of the button. Remove the wrapping `$(function(){})`. And the `this` keyword is the `<button>` element and not the `<div>`

Comment: Just an FYI, the C in Class is supposed to be capitalized. Also, ID should be unique. If you want to share an id between elements, use a class instead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the jquery functions addClass() and removeClass().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has several aspects so will try to adress each one by one. If you use the chrome dev tools you can see that the console reports `Uncaught ReferenceError: next is not defined`. To get of this error move the `function next()` outside of document ready. So this

```
// this does not work
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    function next(){
         $(this).removeclass('show').addclass('hidden');
    }
});
```

becomes this

```
function next(){
    $(this).removeclass('show').addclass('hidden');
}

$( document ).ready(function() {    
    // next moved outside   
});
```

As you now can see you do not need the `document.ready` anymore.

The next error you can see on the chrome dev-tools is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'removeclass'`. The reason is that the method (as others have already said) is **[removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass)**

[image: chrome dev tools - console error message]

Changing this error and the one with `addClass` i added `console.log('this', this);` to find out to which object `this` points

```
function next(){
    console.log('this', this);
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
}
```

Now you can see in the chrome dev tools that `this` points to the object `Window`. So you have to reconsider how you make sure that next() points to the right object. I like to pass the id or in this case the jQuery selector (# + id).

```
<div id='d-1' class='isActive'>first one<br />
    <button onclick="next('#d-1');">Next</button>
</div>
```

I changed the class names based on my understanding what you mean.

```
function next(jQSelector){      
     $(jQSelector).removeClass('isActive').addClass('isPassive');
}
```

#### Demo with first part

No this works for the first `<div id='d-1' ...`. Take a **look at [demo 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ah3hYYElJOJYURL1taYh?p=preview)**. But i assume you want more. It really depends on what you mean.  Should a click on the button for d1

- color d2 green and d1 red
- or should d1 be made green and the next div (d2) red.

### Option 1 make current active (red) all others passive (green)

In this demo **[under the second headline](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ah3hYYElJOJYURL1taYh?p=preview)** a button click makes the parent div active (red-color) all others passive

```
<div id='d-1' class='myDivs isActive'>first one<br />
    <button onclick="makeActive('#d-1');">make active</button>
</div>
<div id='d-2' class='myDivs isPassive'>Second one<br />
    <button onclick='makeActive();'>make active</button>
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
function makeActive(jQSelector){

    console.log('makeActive', jQSelector, $(".myDivs"));
    // set every element with class .myDivs to passive
    $(".myDivs").removeClass('isActive').addClass('isPassive'); 

    // only set one element to active   
    $(jQSelector).removeClass('isPassive').addClass('isActive');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, I need to clarify  my question.

Answer (score 2):

> your "addclass" and "removeclass" should be camel case "addClass" and
>   "removeClass" like this.

Use .toggleClass() instead of use .removeClass() and .addClass() for the same element.

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function() { 

      $(this).parent().toggleClass('show hidden');
    });

});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/117/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change it successively, for example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/127/), click next to show the next one, click last to show the last one. Maybe I am not make myself clear in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question . You have two buttons ah one next and another last ah?

Comment: Yea, I shall edit the original question in a while, but first let me have some try.

Comment: I have get this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/141/ but the last of the last click all will disappear, how to fix this?

Comment: it is easy check length like this -$(this).parent().next().length

Comment: Welcome on first case i didn't understand your question now i understood thanks @vanabel